# axios и fetch не видят локального сервера на node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Сервер на node js порт 8080
Клиент на React порт 3000
При попытке считать данные get запросом,
React не видит локальный сервер

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/user/')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.props.setUsers(data)
      });
  }
```

Конструктор запроса в node js

```
    async getUser(req,res){
        const users = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM person`)
        res.json(users.rows)
    }
```

Проверял в Postman, все работало. В json полный массив user

Comment: Что значит «не видит локальный сервер»?

Comment: Вангую ошибку cors